# Have a blog with a max of 5 items

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I currently have this blog but I'd like to restrict it to some degree:

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

views.py

```
class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'


class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'


class BlogCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_new.html'
    fields = ['title', 'author', 'body']


class BlogUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_edit.html'
    fields = ['title', 'body']


class BlogDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

urls.py

```
from .views import (
    BlogListView,
    BlogDetailView,
    BlogCreateView,
    BlogUpdateView,
    BlogDeleteView,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/',
         BlogDeleteView.as_view(), name='post_delete'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/edit',
         BlogUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_edit'),
    path('post/new/', BlogCreateView.as_view(), name='post_new'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('', BlogListView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

Is it possible to create a Django blod which only allows a maximum of 5 items and anything that is added after the 5th item should overwrite the oldest item? If so how is it done?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Here is a different approach: when listing the blog posts, do not show more than the five more recent posts. When a user tries to access a post (DetailView) just ensure that it is one of the five most recent posts, otherwise return `404 Not Found` (`410 Gone` would be even more appropriate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already answered your own question. When a new blog item is posted, simply locate the five most recent posts (including the one that was just posted) and delete (or mark as hidden) all other posts.

I find it would make more sense to simply not allow access to older blog posts and only retrieve the five most recent posts. This would let you keep all the old blog posts as an archive for the staff and prevent accidental deletions.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I added the following to the model `blog = Blog.objects.order_by('-date')[:5]`

Comment: Makes perfect sense!